# Trying to get data from HTML table using Selenium WebDriver for Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium and I've been trying to make the test suite gather data from a table. I don't have the slightest clue on how to do this.

Here's the table I am working with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrnjj.png

New appointments (dates) are randomly added at random times of the day. I've created a test suite that will constantly refresh at this page. The next step, would be to save all the dates in the table, create a loop to compare if the dates after a refresh happen to be different the original stored dates.

If they are different, notify the user.

Here's a theoretical example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
//Navigate to the appointment page

//Store all the current dates from the table

  for (until a new appointment pops up)

    {
     //Refresh the page
    // Compare the dates to the stored dates
       if (the dates =/ stored dates)
         {
          notify the user(me in this case)
         }
    }
```

I'm also trying to figure out how I can find the element ID of the table.

Here's a screenshot with some of the html code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMtof.png

The statement that is highlighted has the first date stored.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried replicating a similar HTML structure (in fact 2 of them, one after the refresh). Here is a quick solution for you to compare the HTML tables after refresh.

The key here is organizing your table data into a `Map<String, List<String>>` like data structure.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class CheckTables {

public WebDriver driver;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    CheckTables objTest = new CheckTables();
    objTest.runTest();

}

public void runTest(){

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.navigate().to("file:///D:/00_FX_WorkSpace/X_Hour/RoadTest_1.html");
    Map<String, List<String>> objTable_1 = readTable();
    System.out.println("TABLE:1" + objTable_1);

    //event to refresh the table
    driver.navigate().to("file:///D:/00_FX_WorkSpace/X_Hour/RoadTest_2.html");
    Map<String, List<String>> objTable_2 = readTable();
    System.out.println("TABLE:2" + objTable_2);

    compareTables(objTable_1, objTable_2);

}

public Map<String, List<String>> readTable(){

    Map<String, List<String>> objTable = new HashMap<>();

    List<WebElement> objRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr#data"));
    for(int iCount=0; iCount<objRows.size(); iCount++){
        List<WebElement> objCol = objRows.get(iCount).findElements(By.cssSelector("td.tableTxt"));
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int col=0; col<objCol.size(); col++){
            columns.add(objCol.get(col).getText());
        }
        objTable.put(String.valueOf(iCount), columns);
    }

    return objTable;
}

public void compareTables(Map<String, List<String>> objTable1, Map<String, List<String>> objTable2){


    for(int count=0; count<objTable1.size(); count++){

        List<String> objList1 = objTable1.get(String.valueOf(count));
        System.out.println(objList1);
        List<String> objList2 = objTable2.get(String.valueOf(count));
        System.out.println(objList2);

        if(objList1.containsAll(objList2)){
            System.out.println("Row [" + count + "] is SAME");
        }
        else{
            //notify
            System.out.println("Row [" + count + "] has CHANGED");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here are the HTML snippets for RoadTest_1.html and RoadTest_2.html --
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43c3b1f44817c69bd03d/

Comment: Tried out the code you suggested. Getting an initialization error saying: readTable() should not be static.

Also in readTable(), there is an error under 'driver' saying I cannot make a static reference to a non-static field.

Comment: I had the entire code in a class and calling the methods from main. Are you creating an object of the class and then calling the methods ? If yes, then the methods should not be static.

Comment: Edited the snippet to avoid static objects.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it, program now runs. For the output however, I just get

Table 1: {}

-refreshes-

Table 2: {}

Comment: Change the selector in readTable()  as per your HTML attributes

Comment: Yes your `<tr>` are a bit tricky, simply put the selector as `tr` in readTables method and try

Comment: Awesome, thank you Dharam. Using just "tr" gets the information for everything. I would somehow like to figure out how it can only compare the dates.

Row 16, 17, 18 are the ones that hold the dates so maybe I can only compare the values for those rows. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Cool, yes as I mentioned your `tr` are quite tricky, if we could get a unique selector for that it can solve this.